# Сослагательное наклонение в русском — из французского?

Tags: наклонение

Боюсь, этот вопрос будет как off-topic, но мне не к кому обратиться больше.

В испанском мы используем сослагательное наклонение по-другому, чем вы в русском языке: этим наклонением мы эмоционально оцениваем наши высказывания. Была очень рада, когда наконец нашла сходство в наших языках: мы и вы аналогично используем сослагательное наклонение в придаточных цели. Начала думать о возможном объяснении этому феномену, и не дальше.

Насколько я знаю, у России не было контактов с Испанией. У вас был языковой контакт с Францией, не так ли? Если есть историки среди вас (or anyone who knows), не могли бы вы подсказать, верно то, как я думаю? К сожалению, не нашла доказательств, но осмелюсь предположить, что такая синтаксическая структура (использование целевого союза + сослагательная форма глагола) пришла к вам через французский, а мы имеем её, соответственно, через латинский язык.

Как вы считаете, можно так обосновать or is it too bold of me?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93278/discussion-on-question-by-anonym--).

Comment: Вопрос о конструкциях, вроде "Lo he hecho para que estéis contentos"?

Comment: Вопрос больше подходит https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Нет, сослагательное наклонение в русском осталось от праиндоевропейского языка (откуда, вероятнее всего, также перешло и в романские языки).

Из "Исторической грамматики русского языка":

> В древнерусском языке сослагательное наклонение образовалось
>   сочетанием форм аориста от глагола *быти* и причастия прошедшего времени
>   на *-л*, изменявшегося по родам и числам (ажь бы миръ твьрдъ былъ (Смол.
>   Гр. 1229 г.)). Очень рано форма сослагательного наклонения претерпела
>   изменения: вспомогательный глагол начинает терять согласование с
>   подлежащим (происходит колебание в употреблении форм аориста от *быти*),
>   и центром наклонения становится причастие на *-л*. Постепенно все это
>   приводит к тому, что из всех аористных форм в сослагательном
>   наклонении остается лишь форма *бы*, которая по происхождению является
>   формой 2 – 3-го лица ед. ч. аориста (ср. тъ не бы азъ томъ дошелъ
>   (Кир. Тур. XII в.) – бы вместо быхъ). Бывшая аористная форма *бы*
>   превращается в формообразующуюся частицу сослагательного наклонения.

Comment: Надо бы указать автора "Исторической грамматики русского языка"...

Answer (score 1):

Я прочитала комментарии и ответить попробую не о связях, а о самом сослагательном наклонении, в то числе в придаточных цели.

Одним из значений сослагательного наклонения является **желательность, а желание связано с эмоциями.** Субъект действия имеет желание и предполагает, что его действия будут причиной того, что желание исполнится в будущем. Цель – это ситуация, которая желательна для субъекта.

**Модальность желания** (ирреальная модальность) в придаточных цели выражается **двумя способами:**

1. **Сослагательным наклонением глагола** (глагольная форма на Л, частица БЫ входит в союз):

***Я довез друга до вокзала, чтобы он не опоздал.*** Здесь субъекты действия в главном и придаточном предложении **разные.**

2. **Инфинитивом** (частица БЫ входит  в союз):

***Я поехал на вокзал, чтобы встретить друга.*** Здесь  субъект действия в главном и придаточном предложении **один и тот же.**

В заключение я хотела бы привести **цитату из статьи А.С. Пушкина, в которой он говорит о связях русского языка:**

Как материал словесности, язык славяно-русский имеет **неоспоримое превосходство** пред всеми европейскими: судьба его была чрезвычайно счастлива. **В XI веке древний греческий язык** вдруг открыл ему свой лексикон, сокровищницу гармонии, **даровал ему законы обдуманной своей грамматики, свои прекрасные обороты, величественное течение речи;** словом, усыновил его, избавя таким образом от медленных усовершенствований времени. Сам по себе уже звучный и выразительный, отселе заемлет он **гибкость и правильность.**

В царствование Петра I-го **начал он приметно искажаться** от необходимого введения **голландских, немецких и французских слов**. Сия мода распространяла свое влияние и на писателей, в то время покровительствуемых государями и вельможами; к счастию, явился Ломоносов.

Источник: http://pushkin-lit.ru/pushkin/text/articles/article-008.htm